# how to enable button when form is valid

Tags: javascript, angular

could you please tell me how to disable and enable button when form is valid

I have few condition in form .

> Name on Card: A string consisting of  English alphabetic letters only.
>
> Card Number: A string consisting of exactly 16 numbers.
>
> Expiration Month: A 2-digit integer denoting the card's expiration
>   month.
>
> Expiration Year: A 2-digit integer denoting the card's expiration
>   year.
>
> CVV/CVC Number: A string consisting of exactly 3 numbers.

I tried to add this using reactive form here like this but not able to set all condition and disable the button .

```
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.paymentForm = this.fb.group({
      cardname: ['', [Validators.required ,Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z ]+$')]],
      cardnumber: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern('/^\d{16}$/')]],
      dateofexipire:['', [Validators.required]],
       dateofexipireyear:['', [Validators.required]],
       cvc:['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }
```

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cttwtq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your html on your submit button all you need to do is check the value of your form like the following:

```
<button [disabled]="!paymentForm.valid">Submit</button>
```

**Update:**
To validate CVC the easiest solution is to change the input type to number `type="number" this will utilize the built in browsers validation to restrict it to numbers only and then use Angulars [maxLength() Validator](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#maxlength) to restrict the field to 3 characters

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="123"formControlName="cvc">
```

See updated  [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h3zo2f)

Comment: how to add validation ?

Comment: add validation on date and cvc

Comment: thanks but how i will add validation in cvc and date

Comment: `expire moth` and `year`

Comment: can we add validation on `expire month ` and `date and cvc` as I do in card name and number

Comment: See updated for CVC. Date and Expiration would require a custom validator probably using some regex pattern to match whatever specific date infomation meets your requirements though

Answer (score 0):

First things first: you have some problems with formControlName, card name does not have formControlName and the dates are misspelled.

Now to the problem, to disable the button use the `[disabled]="condition"` syntax.

Also, take a look at the [forms documentation](https://angular.io/guide/forms) for information regarding forms and user input.